# How to reload table row after button from its row is clicked?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Currently I am pulling data out of a database to build a table dynamically. After pulling the data, I want myself and or my users to be presented with an option (button) where if they click the button I can edit/remove this row from the table as well as from the database.

I am new to jQuery so I am not sure what I should use for the `$.ajax()` functionality.
This is my php code:

```
foreach($stmt as $item){

            echo '
            </td>
            <td>'.$item['asin'].'</td>
            <td>'.$item['weight'].'</td>
            <td>'.$item['dimension'].'</td>
            <td>'.$item['category'].'</td>
            <td>';

                    echo '<button type="button" class="btn">Update Me!</button>';

            echo '
            </td>
        </tr>';
    }
    echo '</tbody>
    </table>';
```

This is my jQuery code:

```
      $(document).on('click', '.btn', function() {
    $.ajax({
    //code here etc
    success:function(){
    //what to put here?
    }

});
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? (Just so you know, questions are typically asked with a specific coding problem that you have.)

Comment: _"what to put here?"_ - That depends on what your PHP returns for that Ajax request. Presumably you'd want to include a row id in the request so that your PHP can return just that row, then within your click handler overwrite the current contents of the tr element with the new data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of this is paraphrased - you should be able to get the answer from here. At least well enough to try something and post a fuller example.

1) Each table row needs to have an identifier that the javascript can grab. You may find this easier with a data_ element

PHP has:

```
echo '<button type="button" class="btn" data_id="'.$item['asin'].'">Update Me!</button>';
```

JS has:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function() {
   var id = $(this).attr('data_id');
   ...
```

2) You need a PHP function that returns update data for that row

```
<?php

    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
         $id = $_GET['id'];
         $item = Get Data From Where Ever
         echo '<td>'.$item['asin'].'</td>
               <td>'.$item['weight'].'</td>
               <td>'.$item['dimension'].'</td>
               <td>'.$item['category'].'</td>
               <td><button type="button" class="btn" data_id="'.$item['asin'].'">Update Me!</button></td>';
    }

 ?>
```

3) Use javascript / ajax to get the data

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data_id');
    var self = $(this);
    $.ajax({
       url: 'MyUrl?id=' . id;
       success:function(data){
           $(self).html(data);
       }
    });
}
```

It's not perfect, you'll need to worry about making stuff safe, error checking etc, but that should give you the leg up you need.